# Serverless Framework - Restricting permissions with API gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I've been really struggling with how tedious and complicated it is to get cloud formation templates and serverless to work as intended.

I currently have an API gateway where specific endpoints invoke different lambdas.

I was a `/subscribe` to be open to the world but `/users` to only be accessible via one specific resource. How can I go about this?

```
functions:
  createEmailEntry:
    handler: src/Email.addUser
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: /subscribe
  retrieveAllSubscribers:
    handler: src/Email.getUsers
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /users
```

This auto-generates a policy (inline) for API gateway to hit the retrieve endpoint. What is the proper syntax to say only *some ARN* is allowed to hit the `/users` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a syntax example for only allowing access to 'users' from one specific Arn (while allowing everyone to call subscribe). You need to add a resourcePolicy to the provider.apiGateway section, specify the allowed Arn under "Principal" and allow invocation of the specific API path/resource.

You also want to add an authorizer of type aws_iam to the path in question.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  apiGateway:
    resourcePolicy:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS:
              - /* write allowed Arn here */
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource:
          - execute-api:/stagename/*/users
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal: '*'
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource:
          - execute-api:/stagename/*/subscribe

functions:
  createEmailEntry:
    handler: src/Email.addUser
    events:
      - http: 
          method: POST
          path: subscribe
  retrieveAllSubscribers:
    handler: src/Email.getUsers
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: users
          authorizer: 
            type: aws_iam
```